# Reagarding Xampp installation in linux

Tags: linux, lampp

I am new in linux when installed lampp in my system but i am facing problems:

1.when I start the lampp using terminal with this command (sudo /opt/lampp            /lampp start) on that time I am getting Permission denied error.

2.when I Write localhost in browser on that time I am  getting this error : **Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page** this page.

Please help me if anyone know the solution of this    problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be /opt/lampp start? and not /opt/lammp /lamp start?

Comment: M trying this but its says command not found